# PHP write to text file is making text drop one line every time update

Tags: php

I am working on a very basic client/case management tool. Part of this involved text boxes which use PHP to read/write text to .txt files.

The problem I am having is that every time you click "submit" the text drops down one line. When you first write some text in the text box, you obviously write it on the top line, but when you click submit it drops down one line in the text box. The odd thing is that the first time this happens (so the text shows one line down), the .txt file shows the text actually on line one as it should be (although it shows on line 2 in the text box). However, if you click submit again (for example if adding/changing info in the text box, or even just clicking submit on its own) the text drops down another line in the text box, which does make it drop down a line in the .txt file.

Am I missing something? Is there any way to stop this happening?

This is the code I am using on the page that shows the text box:

```
<form action=".write-case-notes.php" method='post'>
<textarea name='textblock' style="width: 490px; height: 170px; resize: 
none;" >

<?php echo file_get_contents( ".case-notes.txt" ); ?>

</textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Update Case Notes'>
</form>
```

This is the php code that I am using to write to the .txt file:

```
<?php

$f = fopen(".case-notes.txt", "w");

fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"]); 

$newURL = '.parties.php';
header('Location: '.$newURL);

?>
```

The $newURL section of the above code is to make the page return to the page with text boxes after new text has been submitted.

Comment: Don't. There is a reason why database management systems like MySQL and Oracle exist. You are just starting to experience a world of pain if you try to build an application using text files for data storage. By all means revisit this when you've been programming full time for at least 5 years. At that time you should be in a position to understand just how hard the problem you are attempting to solve here really is.

Comment: your relative directories and redirections(probably) are wrong. `$f = fopen(".case-notes.txt", "w");` should be `$f = fopen("./case-notes.txt", "w");` unless the filename is actually `.case-notes.txt` and it's on the same folder with the php file. Also you probably don't have a `.parties.php` file, instead you have `/parties.php` file. `Location` header should have a relative path to the root of your domain, not to your file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The file names do actually have the "." at the beginning and they are all located in the same directory as each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually **have** the blank lines in your own code:

```
<form action=".write-case-notes.php" method='post'>
<textarea name='textblock' style="width: 490px; height: 170px; resize: none;" >

<?php echo file_get_contents( ".case-notes.txt" ); ?>

</textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Update Case Notes'>
</form>
```

So when the HTML is rendered, you...

1. First, open your `<textarea ...>` tag.
2. Then write a blank line **inside** the textarea.
3. Then dump the file contents.
4. You actually dump another blank line after it.
5. Then you close the `textarea` tag.

## Solution 1 (quick & dirty)

Eliminate the blank lines **and** blank spaces **and** new lines from your HTML like this:

```
<form action=".write-case-notes.php" method='post'>
<textarea name='textblock' style="width: 490px; height: 170px; resize: none;" ><?php echo file_get_contents( ".case-notes.txt" ); ?></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Update Case Notes'>
</form>
```

## Solution 2 (a bit more clean-code)

If you want a bit more of clean code:

1. Assign your content into a variable.
2. If you do not use a templating engine like smarty, twig or whatever, template your self with simple PHP substitutions.

> ```
> <?php
>
>     // Content to be substituted.
>
>     $textAreaContent = file_get_contents( '.case-notes.txt' );
>     $textAreaStyle = 'width: 490px; height: 170px; resize: none;';
>
>     // Template to substitute in.
>
>     $template =
> '<form action=".write-case-notes.php" method="post">
>     <textarea name="textblock" style="%s">%s</textarea>
>     <input type="submit" value="Update Case Notes">
> </form>';
>
>     // Render
>
>     $html = sprintf( $template, $textAreaStyle, $textAreaContent );
>     echo( $html );
> ```

Notes:

- I changed the single quotes in yout HTML into double quotes.
- If you open the `<?php` tag and **never** close it, you are 100% sure you are not sending unwanted line terminators or spaces. This is documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

The documentation says:

> If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing
>   tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new
>   lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted
>   effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no
>   intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the
>   script.

- Being in 2018, seriously consider using a templating engine. These links can help:

  - Twig - http://twig.sensiolabs.org/
  - Smarty - https://www.smarty.net/
  - Any other from this article: http://acmeextension.com/best-templating-engine/

Hope to help!

Comment: Amazing thanks! I knew I must be missing something simple... I just didn't expect it to be quite that simple!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing the following:

```
$file = './case-notes.txt';
$f = fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($f, isset($_POST['textblock'])."\n");
fclose($f);
header('Location: ./parties.php');
```

EDIT: made the Location redirect simpler.
Edit: new solution below

```html
<form action="./write-case-notes.php" method='post'>

<textarea name='textblock' style="width: 490px; height: 170px; resize: 
none;" >

</textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Update Case Notes'>
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['textblock'])) {
 $text_block = $_POST['textblock'];
 $file = './case-notes.txt';
$f = fopen($file, 'a');
fwrite($f, $text_block."\r\n");
fclose($f);

}


?>
<br /><br /><br />
<?php $output = file_get_contents( "./case-notes.txt" );
print $output."<br />"; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've given your suggestion a try and the text still drops down in the text box the first time I click submit. However, if I then update the text and click submit again, or just click submit without updating the text, then the text in the text box does not drop down. However, each time I re-click submit, a new line is added to the text file which simply shows the number 1.

Comment: @HaplessCoder I have updated my post try the new solution

Comment: I think `$file = '/case-notes.txt';` should be `$file = './case-notes.txt';` unless it's a txt file stored on root directory of the server.

Comment: @Cemal I was not sure if its stored in the root directory so I went with `/case-notes.txt`

Comment: @JamesBond IMHO, you should have asked about it before posting an answer, as this may lead to errors when it could have worked.

Comment: @Cemal you have a valid point, next time I will surely ask if its root or not. I will update my answer shortly